# FLASK - Running Python Scripts

Tags: python, html, button, flask, raspberry-pi

I have made a webpage using bootstrap which is hosted on a raspberry pi. What I would like to do is to, when a certain button is clicked, is to run a python script. This is all being hosted/run/accessed through a FLASK hosting service.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Post so far what have you tried?Are there any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Run python method in HTML web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36713877/run-python-method-in-html-web-page/37512973#37512973)

I also encountered same issue, and I solved it really easily using this way. (I answered on my own question in that link)

Just redirect button to go any link let's say  button  , and then in flask python file, make a method something like

```
@app.route('/a')
def b(name=None):
    import (python script that you want to import, it should be on same folder to do it easy)
    return render_template('xxx.html',name=name)
```

Comment: Will have a try tonight, thank you for your suggestion! :)

Comment: sure, how did it go?

Comment: Sorry for the late message, I have not been able to access the PI. Will be working on in it in the coming days. Will keep you updated. Thank you.